# How to run an OpenMDAO problem employing pygmo if the library is populated with weakrefs

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, multiprocessing, openmdao, pygmo

I am having trouble trying to parallelize an OpenMDAO problem due to the presence of weakrefs to some object instances within the code. I am serializing the data using Dill, which does not raise any errors. However, when debugging it says that some variables have become NoneType and lost all of their information.

I am trying to optimize the problem using an external optimization library which allows for parallel processing (pygmo). I am expecting to run the same problem in multiple different processes, but instead an error is raised telling me some variables have become NoneType and no longer have attributes.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: I second the request for some sample code; I've never used pygmo before so I can't quickly guess at a script that would replicate things. Perhaps set something up using the simple paraboloid test case from the openmdao docs. A runn-able sample of code that produces the error will go a long way toward getting you some help.